# I need to analyze Monte Carlo based Mann Kendall power analysis for time series data in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner, the data is time series as given.

```
head(simdata)

     Rain
1 2680.337
2 2576.450
3 2023.110
4 2198.540
5 2404.990
6 2631.903

library(trend)

alpha = 0.05
sims_run<-2000
save_p <- vector(length=sims_run)
simdata <-read.csv("trend.csv", T)
for(i in 1:sims_run){
  x <- c(simdata)
  t.out <-mk.test(x)
  save_p[i] <- t.out$p.value
}

decision <- length(which(save_p < alpha)); paste("decision=",decision)
power <- decision/sims_run; paste("power=", power)
```

I get the error:

> Error in mk.test(x) : 'x' must be a numeric vector

Comment: `simdata` is a `data.frame` and `mk.test` appears to want `numeric` data.

Comment: Replace `x <- c(simdata)` by `x <- simdata$Rain`.

Comment: If you read [?mk.test`](https://github.com/cran/trend/blob/master/R/mk.test.R#L21), it states that `x` is *"a vector of class "numeric" or a time series object of class "ts")..."*.

Comment: (Unless you want to change the column used in each iteration, you can move the `x <- simdata$Rain` (or whatever) assignment to *outside* the `for` loop, it doesn't need to be rewritten as the same values each time.)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.
First of all, the data is a data.frame, `c()` will not make of it a vector.
Second, in the question you are running the same test repeatedly. In the code below, I resample from the data and run a test on each of those samples.

```
library(trend)

set.seed(2021)    # Make the results reproducible
alpha <- 0.05
sims_run <- 2000

save_p <- numeric(sims_run)

for(i in seq_len(sims_run)){
  x <- sample(simdata$Rain, replace = TRUE)
  t.out <- mk.test(x)
  save_p[i] <- t.out$p.value
}

decision <- sum(save_p < alpha)
paste("decision=", decision)
#[1] "decision= 48"

power <- mean(save_p < alpha)
paste("power=", power)
#[1] "power= 0.024"
```

---

Simpler, with `replicate` there is no need for a loop.

```
mk <- function(x){
  y <- sample(x, length(x), replace = TRUE)
  mk.test(y)$p.value
}

set.seed(2021)
save_p2 <- replicate(sims_run, mk(simdata$Rain))
mean(save_p2 < alpha)
#[1] 0.024
```

---

### Data

```
simdata <-
structure(list(Rain = c(2680.337, 2576.45, 2023.11, 2198.54, 
2404.99, 2631.903)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```